# How to send email from yahoo id from my console application

Tags: c#

Well m searching hard on google but unable to find any working code that will let me send email using my yahoo id on any account using console application.

Can any body help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587))
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youraccount@yahoo.com", "secret");
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@yahoo.com");
    mail.To.Add("destaccount@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test mail";
    mail.Body = "test body";
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

And if you are using .NET versions prior to 4.0, [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) doesn't implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) so you might need to remove the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("from@yahoo.com", "to@domain.com");
message.Subject = "Hello";
message.Body = "Some text";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 465);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Send(message);
```

Server settings is from http://techblissonline.com/yahoo-pop3-and-smtp-settings/